# Deferent output for same For loop and list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

This code transforms list of strings Example:

```
rows = ["pet:1,car:0", "name:0,bar:2"]
```

to list of tuples

```
result = [("person","1"), ("pet","0")]
```

I have the for loop :

```
for items in rows:
    list_of_strings = items.split(",") #Example: ["pet:0", "car:0"]
    listchange = []
    for id_string in list_of_strings:
        listchange.append(tuple(id_string.split(":")))
    print(listchange)
```

This will print list with tuples inside which basically is the desired output:

```
>> [("pet", "1"),("car", "0")]
>> [("name", "0"),("bar", "2")]
```

My problem is when I try to rewrite the same for loop in the following list comprehension I get different output than the desired:

```
 results = [
        {
        "id": [tuple(id_string.split(":"))
                              for id_string in items.split(",")
                              if '' not in id_string.split(",")
                             ]
        }for items in rows]
```

This gives me:

```
>> [{id: [["pet", "1"],["car", "0"]]},
    {id: [["name", "0"],["bar", "2"]]}]
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
>> [{id: [("pet", "1"),("car", "0")]},
    {id: [("name", "0"),("bar", "2")]}]
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Running your code works fine for me (tested both version of Python)

Comment: Thanks for running my code. Are you sure it gives you list of tuples in the second case? It doesn't work for me...

Comment: See my answer, I included the output.

Answer (score 0):

I did run this code,

```
row = ["pet:1,car:0", "name:0,bar:2"]
results = [{"id": [tuple(id_string.split(":")) for id_string in id.split(",") if '' not in id_string.split(",")]} for id in row]
print(results)
>>>> [{'id': [('pet', '1'), ('car', '0')]}, {'id': [('name', '0'), ('bar', '2')]}]
```

Now, I can see two strange things in your code which are both included in that line of your list comprehension,

```
for id in rows
```

1. `rows` in undefined, you used `row`
2. Don't use `id` since it is a reserved keywords in Python for [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#id) function.

This would probably be more appropriate,

```
results = [{"id": [tuple(id_string.split(":")) for id_string in item.split(",") if '' not in id_string.split(",")]} for item in row]
```